# VBA select all items in a pivot report filter greater/less than a number

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

I have a pivot table report filter for the week of the year and I want to be able to select weeks up to a particular number. For example filter out all weeks greater than week 18.

I have some code below that loops through the report filter and unselects all weeks greater than current week. However, this takes a few seconds to run and I would prefer something more instantaneous (I am also trying to avoid loops in my work wherever possible).

I have tried to use PivotFields.Add but I have encountered a collection of runtime errors. Is this something that can be done without a loop?

```
Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
Set PvtTbl = Worksheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable2")

PvtTbl.ClearAllFilters

PvtTbl.PivotFields("Week_Of_Year").PivotFields.Add Type:=xlValueIsLessThanOrEqualTo, Value1:=18
```

Comment: Ironically, you can't add a filter expression to a report filter, only to row/column fields.

Comment: @Rory right well that explains the errors - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you might not be able to interact with the fields in the filters selection, you can still apply filters directly to columns within the pivot table.  Reading what you're looking for, I think this might get you there.

`PvtTbl.PivotFields("Week_of_Year").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionIsLessThanOrEqualTo, Value1:=18`